# How can i read first item inside multiple arrays in IOS

Tags: ios, arrays, json, arraylist

I have this Array, and i need all first elements.

I can only read one with this

```
vc.ArrayListaFotos = [[listaImagens objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row * 3)] valueForKey:@"Caminho"];
```

But I can't read others first itens inside array 1,2,3...

[image]

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: It's an array of arrays and you need the first object of all the nested arrays?

Comment: just do it in loop? for(int x=0;x<vc.ArrayListaFotos.count;x++) {


}

Comment: @stepik21 `forin` is much better.  See my answer.  ;)

Comment: yep, you're right :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong reference. You should do that:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayDeImagensParaOProdutoSelecionado = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:nil];
for (NSArray *tempArray in listaImagens) {
    if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [tempArray valueForKey:@"idProduto"]] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[produtos objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row * 3)] valueForKey:@"id"]]]) {
        [arrayDeImagensParaOProdutoSelecionado addObject:tempArray];
    }
}
```

Hope it help.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(NSArray *innerArray in outerArray) {
    NSObject *firstObject = [innerArray firstObject];
    // do whatever you need to with firstObject
    NSLog(@"%@",firstObject);
}
```